# Unity3D: Published game to Play Store with Upload certificate SHA key, so leaderboards are not working for users

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, keystore, sha, android-app-signing

This was my first game launch, I have published my game to play store using the Upload certificate SHA key, instead of App signing certificate.

So my leader boards are not working.

What should I do now, how do I change the SHA key in the Key Store to the App signing certificate and publish an update to the app?

I do not have many users as I have not promoted it to anybody yet.
Please tell me the steps to change the SHA key in Unity.

I can't recall how I added the upload certificate SHA key to Unity in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the artifact signed with the upload key is normal. You can find the SHA of the app signing certificate in the *App Signing* page of the Play Console.

This post [Android App Bundle kills Google Play Games integration - Working with plain old APK - How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148182/android-app-bundle-kills-google-play-games-integration-working-with-plain-old/62183230#62183230) explains how to register the right SHA.

Comment: I have added the App Signing key in Google API Console. I opened the Keystore generated using keytool.exe, There the SHA value is for Upload Certificate. So leaderboard shows the spinner, no scores. How to edit the Keystore value and if i edit it, will it not change the keystore which cause Play store not accept my  app bundle as the keystore is different.